# Typescript: Generic type of method params to match type of callback function params

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to make a class that accepts a function in the constructor. The function can have arguments of any type. Then I want to put a method on the class that accepts that same arguments as function parameter, as it will be a wrapper around this callback. Here's a simplified example to show what I'm trying to do

```
interface Options<T> {
   callbackFn(...x: any[]) => Promise<T>
}

class ExampleClass<T> {
  private options: Options<T>;
  result: T;

  constructor(options: Options<T>) {
    this.options = options;
  }

  async wrapperFn(...x: any[]) {
    // Do some stuff before the callback

   this.result = await this.options.callbackFn(x)
    
   // Do some stuff after
  }
}

const example = new ExampleClass<string>({
  callbackFn: (a: string, b:string) => new Promise((res) => {
    res(a + b);
  })
});

example.wrapperFn("foo", "bar")
```

This is basically the way I have it now, and it works but it obviously doesn't enforce the types of the params of wrapperFn which isn't ideal. Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: You need to make `Options` generic in the argument types as well as the return type, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbAzoN).  Does that code meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That's exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the compiler to keep track of both the callback return type and the callback argument list type, then you'll want `Options` to be generic in both the return type (you called it `T` but I'll call it `R` for "return") and the argument list type (I'll call it `A` for "arguments"):

```
interface Options<A extends any[], R> {
  callbackFn(...x: A): Promise<R>
}
```

Now you can just use `A` anywhere you were using `any[]` before, and you'll get stronger typing.  This also implies that `ExampleClass` needs to be generic in `A` and `R` too:

```
class ExampleClass<A extends any[], R> {
  private options: Options<A, R>;
  result?: R;

  constructor(options: Options<A, R>) {
    this.options = options;
  }

  async wrapperFn(...x: A) {
    // Do some stuff before the callback
    this.result = await this.options.callbackFn(...x)
    // Do some stuff after
  }
}
```

Let's test it out:

```
const example = new ExampleClass({
  callbackFn: (a: string, b: string) => new Promise<string>((res) => {
    res(a + b);
  })
});
// const example: ExampleClass<[a: string, b: string], string>

example.wrapperFn("foo", "bar") // okay
example.wrapperFn("foo", 123); // error!
// --------------------> ~~~
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM4A8AgshAB6QgAmeycIAngNoC6ANMgEoB8yA3gFgAUMmQI4AGwkAjRAGsAYiAAUAOnVkAXMiIBKbQAUo2ALbA8EAj2EBfYcIQS4eWgFEycE+gkQAwk5diUgoIalp6ZnYuXkERZHQoYAA3OEhkbEwcfG0MLFxCIg4eAG5hUSgIPABXCTAAfm1OUqEysXywKCqEMGwoZQy87LRM-OIi7l1+VtEwAAtzVQGs2gBedJH8ZtE7FrjnBhAEZAB3KDh0dGglNQ1tPSm40QB6J+QAEWxkPFMUPDAqmAwZDSCAwXooOYocRSWQIOTTZBzBYVaq1ZBrODHODAMCI+Z4RYbAnQmTya7qVRkXQIl7vT7fEy-f6AugwSBQVo7HYOdrBTzeFBrEAQY7Idz8nz+Zx4ZSxUQk2GKEDaZRwbR-RIgADmHGk6o6oC1kxWvGFoqMpnMlg1hu4ymUKONMQRKNVyAA1MDdFtkDZqUI-c1aQheeQJRBtOKvJKAoQmGqvgbtbr9ZqtVEbdruPYhGHoxBVKdzpcoNcAERg7Bljhl2RQMuTWnYORwBjCPMCwtnC5XFQV7BVjgARgATABmb3IWnQYxQACEwlpAFoV6u1+v17wAH47xevIhQLVVRngdJAsAMS7IADkIGPIKg1+Q5mQIGwuOlwC1IDg0h8iM+dA4DORl2TPRFLxQa9My1a9VCAA)